# Install tensorrt on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorrt

I am trying to install tensorrt on my google collab notebook, i chose the GPU runtime type and ran the following command:

```
import os
import torch
```

when i run

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

it return "True". Next i run

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/nougat
!pip install tensorrt
!pip install tensorflow
```

after i ran it several times, all the line in the output all start with "Requirement already satisfied" but when i ran:

```
!tensorrt -h
```

it said:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: tensorrt: command not found
```

Can someone tell me how i can install tensorrt ? I only have basic python programming background (i'm a first year university student) and this is the first time i use something like this so i'm sorry if the question or the description of the problem is bad.